# SQL Server 2005/2008 Finding nth highest salary

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

For Finding nth highest salary I am using

```
select salary from 
  (
   select distinct ROW_NUMBER() over (order by salary desc) as rownum,Salary
   from Employee
  )a
  where rownum=2
```

However if  i have same salary like

```
70000
70000
60000
50000
50000
```

When executing the query i am getting second highest salary

```
70000 instead 60000
```

how to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Mark has already provided one answer, I'd say that you're using the wrong function. You don't want the row number, you want the RANK. And based on how you want to handle duplicates, specifically you should be using [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx).

E.g.:

```
SELECT salary FROM
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rank, salary
    FROM Employee
) T2
WHERE rank=2
```

Comment: Thank you Damien for you clarification

Answer (score 3):

It's the salaries that must be distinct, not the row numbers:

```
SELECT salary FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rownum, salary
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee) T1
) T2
WHERE rownum=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the finding nth highest  Using CTE(Common Table Expression)

```
With Result as
(
select salary ,DENSE_RANK () over(ORDER BY salary DESC) AS Denserank FROM employees
)

select Top 1 salary

FROM Result
where Result. Denserank=2
```